# Illegal attempt to map a non collection

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

We recently upgrade from Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 4.3.19.RELEASE and started 
getting exception after upgraded. Spring version is 4.

Error Stack

```
... 80 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: com.markit.bonds.feed.btds.model.BondFeedTraceTrade.pkey
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.getCollectionBinder(CollectionBinder.java:331)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1922)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:963)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:796)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3845)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3799)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1412)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
at org.spring
```

This was working fine earlier. Can someone point if hibernate has changes in this behaviour with upgrade.

I see answers on stackoverflow to make it collection/set however, wondering how it was working earlier.

```
public class BondFeedTraceTrade {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "hibseq")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "hibseq", strategy = "seqhilo", parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = "max_lo", value = "5"),
            @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "bond_feed_trace_trade_seq") })
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = BondFeedTrace.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pkey")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Long pkey;


public class BondFeedTrace {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "hibseq")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "hibseq", strategy = "seqhilo", parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = "max_lo", value = "5"),
            @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "bond_feed_trace_seq") })
    private Long pkey;
    @Column(name = "CONTRIBUTOR")
    private String contributor;
    @Column(name = "MSGSEQNUM")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can only offer several reasons why what you could do in Hibernate 3 no longer works

#### JPA 2.0 and 2.1 Support

Hibernate 4.2 and 4.3 respectively introduced support for JPA 2.0 and 2.1.  The `@OneToMany` mapping is a JPA mapping and as support for the newer specifications were added, its likely the binding code around those annotations were adapted to adhere to the specification requirements and usage patterns.

This would therefore imply that your usage is no longer valid according to the JPA spec and why the exception explains that you must map your association accordingly.

It is also plausible that Hibernate 3 offered this as a *special use case* that in hindsight or through the development needed for later JPA specification support, it was deemed deprecated and therefore removed entirely.

#### Its was a Bug

Users can be creative and sometimes they find *unconvential* ways of doing something that despite how strange it looks on the surface, it seemingly works for a period of time until either that code is rewritten or replaced by something new or the bug is identified and fixed.

*Either way your mapping is not longer valid and you should adapt it so it is.*